# Set view's rounded corners and shadow

Tags: ios, swift, shadow, rounded-corners

I need to round the bottom left and right corners of a view and base on what I found on the internet I created this function inside an UIview extension:

```
func setRoundedCorner(withRadius radius: CGSize, forCorners corners: UIRectCorner ) {

    let viewShape = CAShapeLayer()
    viewShape.bounds = CGRect(x: self.frame.origin.x, y: self.frame.origin.y, width: self.bounds.width, height: self.bounds.height)
    viewShape.position = self.center
    viewShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: radius).cgPath
    self.layer.mask = viewShape

}
```

Now, I encountered two issues with this solution; despite it works perfectly for a static view, my view changes its height programmatically causing the view to be truncated; I found a workaround to that issue recalling each time the `setRoundedCorner` method, but it's very uncomfortable inside my view; is there any other way to solve this? Another issue harder to me to solve is the shadow set. I usually use this method:

```
func setShadow(height: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, opacity: Float, radius: CGFloat) {
    self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: self.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
}
```

Instead the view appears this way when it should has the shadow under itself:

[image]

But in this situation doesn't seem to work not showing any shadow at all. Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Show us a screenshot of what you get and perhaps a screenshot of your goal.

Comment: (1) You must set the mask's size _after_ you know the view's final size. Also in iOS 11 there is no need for a mask; you can round individual corners. (2) You cannot have both a mask and a shadow, because the mask clips the shadow. — Both matters have been explained here many times. Please search before asking.

Comment: Can we have the expected output?

Comment: @Glenn I edited my question

Comment: @AngryWarden I edited the post showing how appears now the view...It should appear that way but with a shadow under itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I'm sharing with you my category for adding corner radius (using BezierPath) and at the same time supporting adding a shadow.

```
import UIKit

/// A category for all views.
extension UIView {
    /// Setups the layer of a view.
    public func setupLayer(
        cornerRadius: CGFloat = 22,
        borderWidth: CGFloat = 0,
        borderColor: UIColor = .clear,
        shadowOffSet: CGSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1),
        shadowColor: UIColor = UIColor(red:0, green:0, blue:0, alpha:0.15),
        shadowOpacity: Float = 1,
        shadowRadius: CGFloat = 2,
        shouldClipToBounds: Bool = false
        ) {

        self.layer.cornerRadius     = cornerRadius
        self.layer.borderWidth      = borderWidth
        self.layer.borderColor      = borderColor.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset     = shadowOffSet
        self.layer.shadowColor      = shadowColor.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOpacity    = shadowOpacity
        self.layer.shadowRadius     = shadowRadius
        self.clipsToBounds = shouldClipToBounds
    }

    /// Round the corner radius with bezier path.
    func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

Feel free to edit everything on this. Now, let's talk about your problem. By the way, this code, I use this in my production projects. Sometimes you need to round your corners in your `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. And if you're using a subclass of a `UIView` or `UITableViewCell` or similar classes, then you add your rounding corners code inside their `draw` functions.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
    // Round corners here...
}
```

[image]

Finally, for setting up the layers, I usually call it inside the lazy init declaration of my controls (e.g. buttons, textFields...). Know the difference of adding corners using bezierPath and by simply layer.cornerRadius. :)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Ok thank u a lot...I’m gonna try...just a couple of questions...can u explain me the difference between using layer.cornerRadius and bezierPath? I used the last one cause I needed to set only the bottom corners...and another question: what do u mean by the draw function of the custom class?

Comment: Well the layer.cornerRadius does not need to be called inside the ```draw``` / ```viewWillLayoutSubviews``` method. And also you are rounding all the corners using that. While using the BezierPath allows you to round any corner. It can be all corners, topLeft, topRight only, bottomRight and topRight, etc... ```draw``` method (in cells, or UIView) is the equivalent of ```viewWillLayoutSubviews``` of the controllers. Don't forget to select an answer to close your questions. Open a new thread if you want to ask further questions (but make sure it isn't a duplicate) :)

Comment: Yeah...thank you very much...I’ll try your code and then if I solved my issue I’ll select your answer

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't seem to work...there isn't any shadow

Comment: How did you implement it? Which one? See my edited answer, I'll post a sample output.

Comment: I simply called the setupLayer() and roundCorners() inside the viewDidLoad methods and it rounds the corners but it doesn't show any shadow. As I said in another comment...Could it be related to the fact that this view has other elements inside itself and it's a custom view?

Comment: Did you adjust the values to satisfy your requirements? Like shadow opacity, shadow radius? Try setupLayer() first without the roundCorners(). And remember that roundCorners() which uses BezierPath should be inside the ```draw``` or ```viewWillLayoutSubviews```

Comment: If I call the method setupLayer() alone inside the ViewController It does work perfectly showing the shadow and everything but if I also call the roundCorners() method inside the draw method (I point we're talking of a UIView subclass) it rounds the corners but the shadow disappear

Answer (score 0):

**You can simply add this extension**

```
extension UIView 
{ 
func dropShadow(scale: Bool = true) {
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
    layer.shadowRadius = 1

    layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).cgPath
    layer.shouldRasterize = true
    layer.rasterizationScale = scale ? UIScreen.main.scale : 1
}

func dropShadow(color: UIColor, opacity: Float = 0.5, offSet: CGSize, radius: CGFloat = 1, scale: Bool = true) {
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
    layer.shadowOffset = offSet
    layer.shadowRadius = radius

    layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
    layer.shouldRasterize = true
    layer.rasterizationScale = scale ? UIScreen.main.scale : 1
}


 }
```

**After add above extension you can use like below**

```
  priceview.layer.cornerRadius = 5
  priceview.dropShadow(color: UIColor.darkGray, opacity: 0.5, offSet: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1), radius: 3, scale: true)
```

I hope it wil help you.

Comment: It doesn't work...could it be caused by the fact that this view has other elements inside itself and it's a custom UIView?

Comment: yes and it contains many element inside itself and give i give it to drop shadow and it is working fine for me.